# MongoDB - Nested aggregation with sort and limit at each stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My document looks like this:

```
{
  Region: "Europe",
  Country: "Luxembourg",
  Category: "Snacks",
  Sales Channel: "Offline",
  Order Priority: "C",
  Units Sold: 9357,
  Unit Price: 421.89,
  Unit Cost: 364.69,
  Total Revenue: 3947624.73,
  Total Cost: 3412404.33,
  Total Profit: 535220.4,
}
```

Basically, there are multiple countries with the same Region and multiple categories with the same country.

I want to run an aggregation query which returns `top n Regions` with their `top x Countries` with `top y categories` by Revenue. So the response should look something like this or similar:

```
{
  "Region": "Asia",
  "Total": 12345,
  "Countries": [{
    "country": "China",
    "Total Revenue": 1234,
    "Categories": {
      "Snacks": {
        "Revenue": 123
      },
      "Cosmetics": {
        "Revenue": 123
      }
    }
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "Total": 1234,
    "Categories": {
      "Snacks": {
        "Revenue": 123
      },
      "Cosmetics": {
        "Revenue": 123
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

So far I've managed this (it returns countries' total revenue grouped by region) but I have no idea how to further divide it by categories. How do I achieve the required result?

```
[{
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "region": "$Region",
        "country": "$Country",
        "type": "$Category"
      },
      "Revenue": {
        "$sum": "$Total Revenue"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.region",
      "Revenue": {
        "$sum": "$Revenue"
      },
      "values": {
        "$push": {
          "country": "$_id.country",
          "Revenue": {
            "$sum": "$Revenue"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "values": {
        "$slice": [
          "$values",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 2
  }
]
```

The response for the above query looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "Asia",
  "Countries": [{
      "country": "Sri Lanka",
      "Revenue": 731282793.7
    },
    {
      "country": "Vietnam",
      "Revenue": 634208761.24
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have 3 `$group` stages. You miss out on the `$group` (2nd) stage for group by `Region` and `Country`.

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "region": "$_id.region",
      "country": "$_id.country"
    },
    "Categories": {
      $push: {
        k: "$_id.type",
        v: "$Revenue"
      }
    },
    "TotalRevenue": {
      "$sum": "$Revenue"
    }
  }
}
```

Complete query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "region": "$Region",
        "country": "$Country",
        "type": "$Category"
      },
      "Revenue": {
        "$sum": "$Total Revenue"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "region": "$_id.region",
        "country": "$_id.country"
      },
      "Categories": {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.type",
          v: "$Revenue"
        }
      },
      "TotalRevenue": {
        "$sum": "$Revenue"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.region",
      "Revenue": {
        "$sum": "$TotalRevenue"
      },
      "Countries": {
        "$push": {
          "country": "$_id.country",
          "TotalRevenue": "$TotalRevenue",
          "Categories": {
            $arrayToObject: "$Categories"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "Countries": {
        "$slice": [
          "$Countries",
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 2
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2sFdcDP0tgu)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, it works...could you also tell how to limit number of countries and number of categories sorted by revenue in this case ?

Comment: updated playground with multiple docs: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rwyBEWw_EjZ

Comment: You need to perform sort in first stage, sort by "Total Revenue" descending, "Country" and "Region", and perform nested slice for categories. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L9cEjM7IiuF)

Comment: Alright, I'll try to dive deep into this. Thanks for the help.